# RGB LED driver, PWMs seem to interfere with each other

Tags: led, pwm, signal, led-driver, rgb

I have inherited a project from colleague that is leaving the company. This project is a RGB LED driver with three LEDs, red green and blue, that uses an Elmos E521.36 chip. [Its datasheet is available here.](https://www.radiolocman.com/datasheet/data.html?di=513983&/E521) It is not available on the manufacturers website for some reason.

The PWMs in this device is the usual prescaler, period, counter, start and stop which I have found in other devices. The problem is the PWMs generated by this device.

Visually, the colors are the ones I would expect.  For example, if I enable the PWM associated with the red LED, I can see a red color in the LED. However, the PWM signals in this scenario are the following ones:

[image]

I have circled in red the strange behaviour of the green and blue PWMs. Note the pulses are active low. I think in this scenario, the green and blue PWMs should remain at high level, however, pulses seem to be generated on those channels too.

Similarly if I set a  white color by enabling all PWMs, I can see a white color in the LED.  In this scenario, the PWM signals are the ones below:

[image]

It looks like while one the PWMs is active, the other PWMs behave in a strange manner when they should be OFF. I have no explanation for this behaviour and I was wondering if anyone has faced this before.

EDIT1:

I have added a small portion of the schematic.

[image]

Comment: We'll need to see a schematic, and perhaps also a PCB layout.

Comment: Wasn’t an almost identical question asked earlier today? What does Vcc look like on your scope?

Comment: @marcelm I have added a small portion of the schematic, I might have more information tomorrow regarding this.

Comment: @winny You are correct, I have decided to delete the old one and rephrase the question providing more information. Vcc on my scope is stable at ~13.5 Volts during that period. I have noticed that the PWMs, when they should be OFF, they increase to a value closer to 13.5 Volts, which is the original value of voltage supply, then they decrease to the original high level of the PWM when all the PWMs are OFF.

Comment: Driver chip is garbage?

Comment: @winny that might be very well the case, I do not have experience with RGB Led Drivers so no idea whether this behaviour is common. It is the first time I see it. I am thinking that perhaps it does this for EMC purposes, but I guess it should provide a way to disable or modify this behaviour.

Comment: Could it be a capacitive or photoelectric effect due to the leds? Substitute a led with a resistor and test.

Comment: That device is a 16-bit micro with 32kB one-time programmable ROM and 128-byte EPROM... any idea what it was programmed with, if anything? That might very well influence it's behavior.  The datasheet also reads "The [16kB] System ROM content may vary depending on customer requirements."  There are a lot of software unknowns here.